# Why won't Minsc join my party?

Tags: baldurs-gate

Whenever I first met Minsc in the town that he stands around in, all he said was that he didn't like the look of me. Every attempt to reengage him in conversation fails, and I never get the option to have him join my party.

It's been a while since I've played this game originally, but I remember being able to team up with Minsc to save Dynaheir from the Gnoll Fortress.

Thinking it would help, I went ahead and left for the fortress without Minsc, rescued Dynaheir, she joined my party, and I went back to try talking to Minsc again.  He still ignores me even though Dynaheir is in my party!

I don't have any evil characters in my party. The other members are Jaheira, Kaleid, and Imoen.

How do I get him to join up with me?

Comment: its been forever since i played BG1, but i know BG2 had the party reputation metric, although i can't remember if BG1 had this as well. perhaps, if it does, your rep is (still) too low?

Comment: I even went ahead and cleared the mines without Minsc, gaining reputation in the process, and he still won't join me. I remember first playing it long ago, and he was definitely able to join me before heading down into the mines before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I've been able to find your character's charisma is to blame. Baldur's Gate uses reaction rolls which are based on charisma, if you rolled terrible + bad charisma then he won't have anything to do with you.

A couple of people got him to join by increasing their character's charisma (with a character editor) and then removing Dynaheir from the party. After asking Dynaheir to re-join Minsc apparently came along for the ride.

If it isn't the charisma, then it could have something to do with having sub 10 reputation.

Sources:[Bioware Forums](http://forums.bioware.com/viewtopic.html?topic=638972&forum=19) & [Gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/75251-baldurs-gate/52819267)

Comment: Again, it's been years, but didn't Baldur's gate have the option to show the virtual die rolls in the message log? If so, then Christian should be able to use this to see if even a 'natural 20' still fails.

Comment: That only shows combat rolls, not charisma / dialogue based stuff.
And you might be thinking of Temple of Elemental Evil?

Comment: You're right! My character had a pretty bad charisma. I simply removed Dynaheir from my party, and when I talked to her again to rejoin, Minsc came with her!  Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, just to clarify for everyone else, I didn't have to edit my character's charisma. I just made Jaheira my party leader before removing Dynaheir. It's always better to have a high charisma party leader than not, because otherwise you will miss out on many things, like Minsc for example.

Answer (score 4):

It's not just charisma. If you have the magician Edwin join you before Minsc, he won't like you very much. Minsc is guided by his hamster Boo, and I think Boo doesn't really like that magician.

Comment: Also, all Red Wizards of Thay I know are egocentric snobs. So, its quite expected that people do not like them.